# UITableView height issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` to which I add a `UIButton` and `UITableView` as `subviews`. Initially since the table view has no content it's height is zero.

When user takes an action the `UItableView` receives some data and reloads itself.

in `numberOfRowsInSection` I return the count but since the height of `UITableView` is zero call to `cellForRowAt` is not working.

I want to keep the height of `UITableView` zero when no content and give it height when the content is there.

And since `UITableView` is a subview of `UIStackView` it should expand too

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use UITableView's estimatedRowHeight.

Comment: how will that help

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust tableview's frame once it receives data. Check this link:
[UITableView not shown inside UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481153/uitableview-not-shown-inside-uistackview)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I have done something very similar to this and hopefully this helps.

```
final class SignInVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // Whatever max height you are after
    private let maxTableViewHeight = 500
    // Whatever height you are after
    private let rowHeight = 90

    // Just using string array for example but use your own array here
    private var fields: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        setTableViewHeight()
    }

    private func setTableViewHeight() {
        var newHeight = fields.count * rowHeight
        if newHeight > maxTableViewHeight {
            newHeight = maxTableViewHeight
        }
        tableViewHeight.constant = newHeight
    }

    @IBAction func addField(_ sender: Any) {
        fields.append("Test")
        setTableViewHeight()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension SignInVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fields.count
    }

    // Rest of your datasource/delegate below...
    // I am assuming you have your own already

}
```

Hopefully this helps :)